# How to read a file before runing a set of mocha test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am trying to read a file which contains all the inputs for a set of mocha test. While trying to read these file i just get that the inputs(a Map) is null.

Scrapper_cheerio.js is written in the async/ await format however, don't believe that has anyting to do with a file not being read.

if I understand before correctly, the stuff in the before block should happen before any test occur. Currently this is what I have tried :

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const fs = require('fs');

const scrapper_cheerio = require('../scrapper/Scrapper_cheerio');
describe('test1', function(){
    var inputs = null;
    before( function(done){
        fs.readFile('./inputs.txt', 'utf8', 
            function(err, fileContents){
                if(err) throw err;
                const string_data = fileContents;
                const data = eval(string_data);
                inputs = new Map(data);
                done();
            });
    });

    describe('is_null_input()', function(){
        const is_null_input = inputs.get('is_null_input');
        const json_result = scrapper_cheerio.is_null_json(is_null_input);
        it('should return a json string', function(){
            assert.isObject(json_result, 'is json object');
       }); 
    });
```

});

I am just expecting this first test to be true because it happens to be the easiest to test however, I cannot read the file. I am very new to mocha testing hence I may, and probably do have some glaring and obvious errors. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Edit 1 :

so it was pointed out before quickly being erased (why it was really helpful, thank you.) that I need to do an async call and i did. I can now read the file and I can see that I'm reading it however I cannot pass the value to the bottom

```
    describe('test1', function(done){
        var inputs = null;

        before('test1', function() {
            const string_data = fs.readFileSync('./inputs.txt', 'utf8');
            const data = eval(string_data);
            console.log('data uptop')
            inputs = new Map(data);
            console.log(inputs);
            done();
        });

        describe('is_null_input()', function(done){
            const is_null_input = inputs.get('is_null_input');
            var json_result = scrapper_cheerio.is_null_json(is_null_input);
            console.log('these are json results', json_result);
            it('should return a json string', function(){
                assert.isObject(json_result, 'is json object');
        }); 
        });

    });
```

So I can read the file however it is not reachable in the describe.

Comment: What exactly caused `is_null_input()` to fail? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: 'Cannot read property 'get' of null' , a string in the form of a two dimensional array is stored in that file. however I believe the file is not being read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified working test that should get you jumpstarted:

inputs.txt

```js
[[ 'is_null_input', true ]]
```

code.test.js

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('test1', function () {
  var inputs = null;

  before('test1', function (done) {
    fs.readFile('./inputs.txt', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      inputs = new Map(eval(data));
      done();
    });
  });

  describe('is_null_input()', function () {
    it('should return a json string', function () {
      const is_null_input = inputs.get('is_null_input');
      expect(is_null_input).to.equal(true);  // Success!
      // ...
      // var json_result = scrapper_cheerio.is_null_json(is_null_input);
      // console.log('these are json results', json_result);
      // assert.isObject(json_result, 'is json object');
    });
  });

});
```

---

**Details**

The [Mocha run cycle](https://mochajs.org/#run-cycle-overview) runs all `describe` callbacks first, and `describe` callbacks always run synchronously (you can't use `done`, an `async` function, or return a `Promise` in a `describe` callback).

So this line:

```js
const is_null_input = inputs.get('is_null_input');
```

...was running before the `before`, meaning `inputs` was still `null`.

Moving that code *inside* of the test means it will run *after* the `before` and `inputs` will be defined.

It is best practice to not block the JavaScript event loop with `readFileSync`, so the example above uses `done` in combination with `readFile`.